# Angular 12 - Styles from previous route stay on html

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular-router, angular12

I'm having problems when I navigate to another route without a full reload. When I check and compare the html from a navigated route and a fully reloaded route, I can see that the `<styles>` tags created by the previous routes' `scss` remain on the current route, breaking my layout.

I'm having to navigate like this:

```
this.router.navigate([route]).then(() => window.location.reload());
```

Which is less than ideal. I have checked many other answers on this and they all seem to blame the use of `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in the Component decorator but NONE of my components use that directive.

Te offending component is inside an installed package but I have it's source code and there are no `encapsulation` directives.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where did you declare styles? Can you post the component's declaration also?

Comment: If your <style> tags are in index.html or anywhere at all in your html this is a likely behaviour since angular only swaps the content from your <router-outlet> onwards. and not everything around it, since you still need valid html with a <head> and everything. But ask away if that did not help you

Answer (score 0):

hi @Matheu i think that you have implement your css style in the general style file "styles.scss" which is apply on all the components of the project..

please share your style.scss file here so we can help you .